# WPF Drag Drop Panel (like iGoogle, BBC website, blacklight)

Tags: wpf, layout, drag-and-drop, dockpanel

Does anyone know of any control libraries that provide layout management functionality along the lines of iGoogle, the BBC website or the blacklight drag drop panel? The blacklight drag drop panel would be fantastic, but the project seems to have been removed from CodePlex.

I'm looking for a sexy drag & drop layout manager to include in my WPF application, and none of the regular control vendors such as DevExpress, Infragistics or telerik include anything like what I want. They provide a Visual Studio style dock manager, but that feels too clunky and difficult to use. I want my users to be able to naturally drag and drop 'widgets' without fighting with the dock manager.

See here for examples of the type of control I'm looking for:

- http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/
- http://10rem.net/blog/2011/06/27/marketsplus-evolve-ux-inspiration-from-a-great-silverlight-application

Comment: Although the project is deleted, the source code and libraries still exist somewhere.

Comment: Do you know whereabouts I can download it? I Google'd for it but couldn't find any links to download.

Comment: One guy posted this link, but he isn't sure if it is the latest version: https://bpm2.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Blacklight.Controls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed Marketsplus Evolve[1](http://www.marketsplus.com.au/evolve) (the silverlight app you used as an example). I couldn't find any controls to do what you are after, as I searched for quite a while before we ended up building our own. This isn't a perfect answer, it's just pretty much you are unlikely to find any on the market today.

Cheers,

Aaron Bull

Comment: Thanks for the info, you're the most qualified person to answer :) Good work on the app, it's easily the best user friendly Silverlight/WPF implementation I've seen. I've had a good dig around and the only similar dashboard management control that I could find was the Blacklight controls, but they have been pulled from Codeplex. Out of interest, how long did it take you to put together your control?